DLL load failed while importing pyexpat when running executable
Image of Error
So I created an executable for a python script that I was using that formats certain .txt files into formatted excel sheets. I created the .exe using pyinstaller and was using a virtual installer and UPX to condese the file. However when I run the .exe I get this error and then command prompt just shuts down.
I have tried once creating the .exe outside of a virtual environment and even though the executable works in that case (was using anaconda interpreter) the executable was 1GB. I am wondering if there is a missing module that is causing this issue.
I have tried clearing pyinstaller cache files, running it with --clear and forcing it to make a temp build and create a new dist folder outside the project folder but that juts creates issues with actually creating the executable.
